# If a https domain is redirecting to a http domain. Is there any point in having it?

Tags: facebook, http, ssl, https, dns

I looked around the internet to see if there was a clear answer to this, but it looks like there isn't. So, I work for a small company and one of the domains we have, has the SSL certification with it (https://hmc2agency.com); however, it redirects to the new "brand image" (http://www.wearehmc.com). I'm trying to figure out if we should even keep the certification, since it'll be expiring soon.

It's not like we sell things, or need the encryption stream (a term I could be pulling out of no where); however, we do host a few Facebook page tabs (I was told, that they need https domains) on the site. But, they don't use the HTTPS URL for "app."

Ehh I don't know, I just like to code, I'm no network administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference except for the fact that you have encryption on that Domain.

The DNS servers have knowledge that https://hmc2agency.com has a SSL cert and therefore will do everything in its power to maintain the cert and domain but once you redirected the domain to another domain the cert losses its 'power'.

In this case nothing really happens. Its a simple 302 redirect...you should change this to a 301 redirect for SEO purposes.

This is a good article for [how HTTPs works](http://blog.hartleybrody.com/https-certificates/).